# Firebase iOS SDK - Missing Database URL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I get the following error that I have inherited from a previous developer. My app keeps crashing with the following :

```
2016-06-21 22:26:16.828 Drnk[3234:1081556] The default app has not been configured yet.
2016-06-21 22:26:16.832 Drnk[3234:1081556] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MissingDatabaseURL', reason: 'Failed to get FIRDatabase instance: FIRApp object has no databaseURL in its FirebaseOptions object.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

My App delegate has the following code:

```
 FIRApp.configure()
```

My controller where I call the database and the app crashes has the following code:

```
 var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

I have added the google-services-plist file to my project as instructed.

This all works with another app I am developing but I can't solve this.

Comment: Are you using the google-services-plist from your other app? Does the bundle_id in the plist match with your current app's bundle id?

Comment: No  I am using separate files for each , the ones generated by Firebase so the bundle identifiers are correct.

Comment: Do you see an entry for `DATABASE_URL` in your GoogleServices-info.plist file? I'm wondering if somehow the service generated a file without that entry...

Comment: Also, at what point are in your app delegate are you calling FIRApp.configure()?

Comment: Yes i have an entry : https://drnk-201fe.firebaseio.com

Comment: I call FIRApp.confgure() first in application did finish launching with options

Comment: Are you able to post the contents of your appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Comment: Also, do you see anything in the console along the lines of "Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled..."

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      
        FIRApp.configure()
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
        ISAWS.configure_AWS()            //aws config
     
      //test config to load login 
      loggedIn = false
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

Comment: 2016-06-22 01:40:41.287 Drnk[80735:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-22 01:40:41.288 Drnk[80735:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're not calling `FIRDatabase.database().reference()` before viewDidLoad

Comment: I am not, definitely calling it after that

Answer (score 0):

In your class define a var:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
```

then in viewDidLoad

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866188/4833705

I didn't want to add the same code twice and the comments are kinda long so someone might miss this.

Answer (score 0):

Download and replace the GoogleService-info.plist again since you have already registered the database in your account