# Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance. Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

FirebaseApp throws an exception when invoke `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`.

**Error message**

> Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within
> FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.

`Firebase` project configured correctly. `Authentication` works without issue, but cannot connect to `firebase`.

Here is my app level gradle.build file

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    .....

    //Firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
    // Firebase Invitation
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.6.2'
    // Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    // Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'

    // people api request libraries
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
    compile project(':customsupport')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And project level **build.gradle** file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
    }
}
```

An **DatabaseException** will occur in **FirebaseDatabase.class**

```
public static synchronized FirebaseDatabase getInstance(FirebaseApp var0, String var1) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(var1)) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.");
        } else {
...
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if `FirebaseApp` initialized successfully.  Could you try logging the string returned by `FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions().getDatabaseUrl()` to see if the call completes and if the result is null?

Comment: @Bob Snyder getDatabaseUrl() returned null, but getProjectId(), getApiKey() and getApplicationId() returned correct value

Comment: Does your `google-services.json` file have property `firebase_url`?  It will be near the top of the file under `project_info`.

Comment: @Bob Snyder no Bob, only Google api keys, and OAuth client keys, should I generate json again ?

Comment: Try regenerating your `google-services.json`.  It should have a `project_info` object at the top that contains: `project_number`, `firebase_url`, `project_id`, and `storage_bucket`.

Comment: @Bob Snyder Thanks Bob. I have generate again, now I see the firebase_url, Thanks a lot ))

Comment: Great catch Bob!

Comment: Will also work if hardcoding the db url by `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://blahblah-dbf79-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");`. I had this problem because I first copied the `google-services.json` and then I added the realtime database so my json is not updated, and is fixed by the hardcoding of the db url. But once, I had the updated `json`, I remove the db url hardcoding.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I downloaded the `google-services.json` file again, because I just added realtime database.

Your file should have

```
"project_info": {
    "project_number": "123456789",
    "firebase_url": "https://example.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "example",
    "storage_bucket": "example.appspot.com"
  }, 
...
```

Answer (score 20):

If any one face this issue in 2021 then simply follow these steps:-
Add these dependencies in build.gradle/app

```
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
```

and then use databasereference object

```
databaseReference=Firebase.database.getReference("Users")
```

still confused then read this documentation here[1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

Answer (score 14):

This is what I did for an iOS project.

After I downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file and added it to my project I kept getting the crash

> Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within
> FIRApp or from your databaseForApp:URL: call.

After googling around and not finding a concrete answer I looked at the `GoogleService-info.plist` file from another project that I have and the `DATABASE_URL` key was there but was missing in the one with the crash

All you have to do is 3 simple steps:

1- open your google  `GoogleService-info.plist`

2- enter `DATABASE_URL` as the **key** back into the .plist. You get the **value** from step 3

[image]

3- go to your `Firebase console` > `RealtimeDatabase` > `Data` >  copy and paste or enter the `https//...` url `string` from there as the **value** to the `DATABASE_URL` key in `.plist` file from step 2

[image]

Be sure to add the **https//:** part (it might not be obvious from the picture)

Comment: in my case, i was literally missing the databaseURL key value

Answer (score 4):

You can go to the Firebase console:
 1-Select your project. 2-From "Realtime Database" tap on the left menu go to the "Data" tab and here you can easily access  the database URL needed which you can find it at the first line,then please use the following line of code:

DatabaseRefernce mdatabaseref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);.

and you are all set.
 [for example you can find the URL in this picture underlined by red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS27U.png)

Please have a look on this:
[Assign a firebase database url(String) to a Database Reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919140/assign-a-firebase-database-urlstring-to-a-database-reference-variable)

Answer (score 4):

Just add your firebase url inside the getInstance()

`FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("YOUR FIREBASE URL HERE");`

That worked for me.

Comment: That one helped in my case. One finds the URL in the Realtime Database-console. There section "Data", at the top of this editor-panel thing.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your build dependency to 19.7.0 in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
```

The default one set up in `Android Studio -> Tools -> Firebase` used an old version which causes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the versions below implementation packages in build.gradle(modular).

```
dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In Kotlin
Copy your database url from here and then, paste this url in your code.

```
refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://tictic-97910.firebaseio.com/").reference.child("Users").child(firebaseUserId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>https://appName-bgbtty-default-bblebut.firebaseio.com</string>
```

go to *google service* open as source code, then insert this below the google api id (bottom)

Answer (score 0):

if you are encountering such error in 2022 then solve it with this easy steps

1. get your firebase database url
2. put in int the "getInstance()" function

Problem solved for me
[the image shows how i solved my own problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVANR.png)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

First, check the location.

#### US Central 1

```java
FirebaseDatabase db = Firebase.database;
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

#### Other Locations

```kotlin
val db: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("$URL")
```

Answer (score -1):

**google-services.json**
"project_info": {  `"firebase_url":""`<- here is your Realtime Database url`  }

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

This is an issue with your Google p.list. Simply redownload it from firebase dashboard/project settings after you enable Firebase Database.